# Group algebra isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Say that, for a field $K$, a finite group $G$ with subgroup $P$, the set $\{g_1, \ldots, g_n\}$ contains all representatives of right coset of $G$ modulo $P$ (namely, $G = \bigcup_{j = 1}^n g_jP$ and $g_jP \cap g_kP = \emptyset, \ \forall j \neq k$), with $g_1 := e$ the identity of $G$.

**Problem:** Is the group algebra $KG$ isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{j = 1}^n g_i KP$?

**Attempt:** Define $\varphi_j: P \to g_jP$ as $\varphi(e) = g_j$. Extend such a morphism to $\varphi_j: KG \to g_j(KP)$ given by
\begin{align}
\varphi_j\left (\sum_{g \in G}  k_g g \right) := \sum_{g \in G} k_g (g_j \cdot g).
\end{align}
If $\varphi_j$ is an isomorphism for every $j = 1, \ldots, n$, then I can define $\varphi: KG \to \bigoplus _{j = 1}^n g_j KP$ such that $\varphi|_{g_jP} = \varphi_j$ and hence $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

The thing is: I can't show that $\varphi_j$ are all injective.

**Questions:** Am I missing something? Also (and more importantly), is there any other approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The decomposition $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^m g_i P$ extends to $KG = \bigoplus_{i=1}^m g_iKP$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see it. Could you elaborate?